# retrieve an array and display in tableView iOS Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

i have uploaded another array column in the User class of Parse.com and i want to get that array back and display it in a table view. the array is a list of blocked users the user types in.

```
NSString *usernameBlock = [self.blockUser.text];

PFUser *blockedUser = [PFUser currentUser];
[blockedUser addObject:usernameBlock forKey:@"blockedUsers"];
self.blockedRelation = [blockedUser relationForKey:@"blocked"];
[blockedUser saveInBackground];
```

this adds another array column of usernames.

now in my blockedUserVC i want to query that column and get the array to display in a tableView.

i have tried the below but i keep getting crashes:-

```
//tried this
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[query whereKey:@"blockedUsers" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query valueForKey:@"blockedUsers"];
[query whereKey:@"blockedUsers" containedIn:_blockedUser]; //blocked user is an array
[query orderByAscending:@"username"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
    if (error) {
        //  NSLog(@"error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    } else {
        self.blockedUser = objects; //blockedUser is an array
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];
```

How should i query so i get that array?

```
    crashlog:
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: 
'[<PFQuery 0x7fc13150fbe0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key blockedUsers.'
```

Comment: If you say you are getting a crash and you don't say what it is how can we help?

Comment: @Fogmeister it says null is returned so it crashes

Comment: Please copy and paste the crash log. It is there to help diagnose the crash.

Comment: please see crash log in question

Answer (score 1):

```
[query valueForKey:@"blockedUsers"];
```

This line is causing the crash, use include instead. https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide

Also, I think this:

```
[query whereKey:@"blockedUsers" containedIn:_blockedUser]; //blocked user is an array
```

should be:

```
[query whereKey:@"blockedUsers" containsAllObjectsInArray:@[_blockedUser]]; //blocked user is an array
```

This doesn't cause the crash, but it will yield to (from what I understand) the wrong result.

Comment: This is probably another issue, open another question for that. The code you have above is just for retrieving the data. But, be sure you have implemented the delegate and datasource methods correctly in your UITableViewController class and make sure you are using the data to display.

Comment: `[query whereKey:@"blockedUsers" containsAllObjectsInArray:@[_blockedUser]]; //blocked user is an array
` this line causes crash

Comment: What is the crash log?